# QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qwebengineview

Im migrating an application from PyQt4 to PyQt5.

Im trying to override the request interceptor but this doesn't work for some strange reason, this is not getting picked up. I am using PyQt==5.10.0

```
class WebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor(QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def interceptRequest(self, info):
        # info.setHttpHeader("X-Frame-Options", "ALLOWALL")
        print("test")
        print(info.requestUrl()) 
class MyWebEnginePage(QWebEnginePage):

    # adblocker = Filter(open('easylist.txt', encoding="utf8"))

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def acceptNavigationRequest(self, url, _type, isMainFrame):
        # urlString = url.toString()
        # resp = False
        # resp = WebPage.adblocker.match(url.toString())
        #
        # if resp:
        #     print("Blocking url --- "+url.toString())
        #     return False
        # else:
        #     print("TYPE", _type)
        #     return True

         print(url)

         return QWebEnginePage.acceptNavigationRequest(self, url, _type, isMainFrame)
```

This is how I load the browser

```
# init browser
browser = QWebEngineView()
# init profile
profile = QWebEngineProfile()
# add interceptor to profile
interceptor = WebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor()
profile.setRequestInterceptor(interceptor)
# init page setting profile
page = MyWebEnginePage(profile)
page.setUrl(qurl)
browser.setPage(page)
```

Comment: @eyllanesc done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is caused by the constructor that is using `MyWebEnginePage`, as you have placed it using the constructor:

> **QWebEnginePage::QWebEnginePage(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR)**
>
> Constructs an empty QWebEnginePage with the parent parent.

Instead of the second constructor:

> **QWebEnginePage::QWebEnginePage(QWebEngineProfile *profile, QObject
>   *parent = Q_NULLPTR)**
>
> Constructs an empty web engine page in the web engine profile profile
>   with the parent parent.
>
> If the profile is not the default profile, the caller must ensure that
>   the profile stays alive for as long as the page does.
>
> This function was introduced in Qt 5.5.

The solution is to pass 2 parameters: the profile and the parent, also if you are not going to add anything in the constructor it is not necessary to overwrite it as shown below:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineCore import QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView, QWebEnginePage, QWebEngineProfile


class WebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor(QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor):
    def interceptRequest(self, info):
        # info.setHttpHeader("X-Frame-Options", "ALLOWALL")
        print("interceptRequest")
        print(info.requestUrl()) 

class MyWebEnginePage(QWebEnginePage):
    def acceptNavigationRequest(self, url, _type, isMainFrame):
        print("acceptNavigationRequest")
        print(url)
        return QWebEnginePage.acceptNavigationRequest(self, url, _type, isMainFrame)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    browser = QWebEngineView()
    interceptor = WebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor()
    profile = QWebEngineProfile()
    profile.setRequestInterceptor(interceptor)
    page = MyWebEnginePage(profile, browser)
    page.setUrl(QUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50786186/qwebengineurlrequestinterceptor-not-working"))
    browser.setPage(page)
    browser.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```